# Function onOpen not activating when i open my forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

My function onOpen is not activating itself when i reload/open my quetionaire.

```
function onOpen() {

  this.ClearForm();
  this.UpdateForm();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to be sure:

```
function onOpen() {
  Logger.log(new Date());
  this.ClearForm();
  this.UpdateForm();
}
```

The check logs.  If ClearForm or Update form require permission then they can't be run by simple triggers.  Try installable trigger instead.

[Simple Trigger Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)

Answer (score 2):

`onOpen()` for forms only runs when you open it to `edit` the form:

> [* The open event for Google Forms does not occur when a user opens a form to respond, but rather when an editor opens the form to modify it.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers)

Comment: its anyway i can make this functions run when a user opens a form to respond?

Comment: @Bernardo No`````````.`````````